# How to find CDN is enabled to my google cloud bucket or not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I have enabled "**allUsers**" with "**storage legacy object reader permission**". Now how can i find CDN is active or not ? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To use a Google Cloud CDN with Cloud Storage requires an HTTP(S) Load Balancer. To see if you have a CDN configured, look at the configuration for your load balancers. You can also check the Cloud CDN page in the Google Cloud Console:

https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/cdn/list

Answer (score 1):

In addition of @JohnJanley answer, you maybe have been confused by this [feature description](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-dynamic)

> Cloud Storage behaves essentially like a Content Delivery Network (CDN) with no work on your part because publicly readable objects are, by default, cached in the Cloud Storage network.

Cloud Storage acts as a CDN, but it's not a CDN and it doesn't use Google CDN. For controlling the cache, you can [play with metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-cache)

Comment: To be precise, Cloud Storage has a simple caching layer - provided the correct cache headers are set - but does not provide global caching or the reduced Cloud CDN egress rate.

Answer (score 1):

First setup the base components:

1. Create storage bucket
2. Create HTTP(S) Load Balancer and tick the CDN checkbox

Next, for each object to be cached:

1. Make the object [publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)
2. Set object metadata [cache-control headers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control) to include `public` and an `max-age` to store in the cache, for example `Cache-Control:public,max-age=3600`

To test if an object was served by the Cloud CDN access the object using your load balancer's hostname and look for the [`Age:`](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/troubleshooting-steps#responses-not-cached) response header which is added by Cloud CDN:

`$ curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://example.com/style.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 12:00:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 1977
Cache-Control: max-age=86400,public
Via: 1.1 google
Age: 2`